# ¿Cómo imprimo varios espacios en blanco en php?

Tags: php, html

¿Cómo imprimo varios espacios en blanco en php, intente de todo y no sale?

Estoy tratando de imprimir pirámides con astericos (`*`) como se muestra en esta imagen:

[image: este es el ejercicio que debo resolver]

Me sale, pero no imprime los espacios, le puse (-) para que de la forma; aun sigue el problema de imprimir espacios.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
$nva=5;
$i=1;
$f=1;
/*$es=" ";*/
while ($i <= $nva) {
    $j=1;
    while ( $j<= $i) {
        echo "*";
        $j++;
    }
$e=0;
    while ( $e<= ($nva-$i)){
        /*echo $es;*/
        echo "_" ;
        /*echo str_repeat(' ', 1);*/
        $e++;

    } 

$g=$nva;
    while ( $g>= $i) {
        echo "*";
        $g--;
    }

$e=0;
    while ( $e<= $f){
        /*echo $es;*/
        echo "_" ;
        /*echo str_repeat(' ', 1);*/
        $e++;

    } 


    $g=$nva;
    while ( $g>= $i) {
        echo "*";
        $g--;
    }

$e=0;
    while ( $e<= ($nva-$i)){
        /*echo $es;*/
        echo "_" ;
        /*echo str_repeat(' ', 1);*/
        $e++;

    } 


$j=1;
    while ( $j<= $i) {
        echo "*";
        $j++;
    }
echo "<br>";

    $i++;
    $f+=2;

}
/*echo str_repeat (" ", 10); */



?>
```

¿Por qué ocurre ese problema y cómo puedo resolverlo?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Coloca el codigo que has intentado

Comment: me sale, pero cuando pongo cualquier cosa que no sea espacios en blanco

Comment: Si estás escribiendo un resultado html, como es el caso (por la cabecera que envías) para añadir espacios tienes que escribir el html correspondiente. En este caso, es `&nbsp;` . En caso de un salto de línea, sería con `<br>`

Comment: @Jakala gracias, tenias razón.

Comment: @Jakala por favor, pon eso como respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Si estás escribiendo un resultado html, como es el caso debido la cabecera que envías, para añadir espacios tienes que escribir el html correspondiente.

En este caso, los caracteres serian:
    para el espacio en blanco: `&nbsp;`
    para el salto de línea, sería con `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes Utilizar algo asi:

```
echo 'Primera linea' . "\n";
echo 'Segunda Linea' . "\n";
echo 'Tercera Linea' . "\n";
```

El Resultado seria algo asi:

```
Funcionario Ovisys Dev Marcar Entrada
Funcionario Juan Perez Marcar Entrada
Funcionario Carmen Rotela Marcar Entrada
```

Para mas info puedes verla por Aqui: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.echo.php

Answer (score 0):

una solución simple es combinar &nbsp más un espacio en blanco :

```
echo "primera palabra"."&nbsp "."segunda palabra";
```